# Merging two shapefiles only for those polygons that have same boundaries or within tolerance distance using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, polygon, merge

I have two shapefiles for district boundaries of India in 2001 and 2020. Because boundary of districts changed over time since districts merge and split, I want to export only those districts (they are polygons in shapefile) that have the same boundaries in both years (or are located within the tolerance distance, e.g. 10km).

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1.

Comment: the mission is to get the districts from both the layers matching/overlapping 100%??

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to trace only those districts that did not change over time and thus have the same polygons in both shapefiles. (or within tolerance 10 km)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and merge the datasets into a single dataset then run [Find Identical](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/find-identical.htm) tool?

Before you merge make sure you add a field so that you can identify which dataset they came from.

Comment: This doesn't work because districts were just placed under a newly formed state. So state name is different in 2 shapefiles for the same district name. That is why i want to do it for polygons because they didn't change, only names changed.

Comment: Find Identical works with the Shape field, not only the attribute fields. This is documented in the Help file.